# Mongoose: Cast to ObjectId failed for value on newly created object after setting the value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Even though this has been asked many times it usually is because the entity has no valid ObjectId for the field.

I came across a situation where the ObjectId was set to a value that can be casted to ObjectId but still get this error.

The Schema:

```
var serviceSchema = paramMongoose.Schema({
  serviceName:{ 
   type: paramMongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId
   , ref: 'servicenames',required:true 
  }
});
```

pseudo code:

```
serviceFromDB=new Service({serviceName:'some Name'});
serviceFromDB.serviceName='000000000000000000000001';
serviceFromDB.save(function(paramError,paramData){
  if(paramError){
    console.log('but but but...',serviceFromDB,paramError)
  }
});
```

The output of this code is:

> but but but... { serviceName: 000000000000000000000001,
>   _id: 55079a90286f49280364f78b } { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "some Name" at path "serviceName"]

Note that the **serviceName is castable to ObjectId** but mongoose uses the value provided to the constructor instead of the value set after that.

Using the [documented set function](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-set) results in the same error:

```
serviceFromDB.set('serviceName','000000000000000000000001');
```

This was code that updates or insert an entity so fields are set later. Solution was to create a service instance without passing an argument:

```
serviceFromDB=new Service();
```

Opened an [issue](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/2766) for this as it's very unintuitive behavior of a document/entity to use a value set in the constructor even after re setting it later.

Comment: A completely irrelevant answer marked as a duplicate? I can google and use the so search as well my friend but that answer has nothing to do with what caused the problem. A lot of things could cause this error like querying or trying to populate using a non casteble value. The problem here describes a save operation and even in the error the object logged has a valid object id yet mongoose tries to cast a value to ObjectId that is no longer the current value.

Comment: Yeah, I think they jumped the gun a bit quick on this one. Reviewers please note that this is the same error as the duplicate but a different cause and fix.

Answer (score 3):

Solution was to create a service instance without passing an argument:

```
serviceFromDB=new Service();
```